# Updating Fields in Jira in Python using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, jira

I am trying to update a custom field in Jira, using the following code and I'm getting a 415 error code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  My code is below:

```
import json
import requests

jiraSession = requests.Session()


username =  input("username: ") 
password =  input("password: ")   

#-------------- CALL -----------------

searchAPI = 'http://ourbaseurl.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-1'
holder = requests.put(searchAPI, auth=(username, password), data=
    {"update":
        {"customfield_1000":
            {
                "set":
                    {
                        "value": "FIELD VALUE"
                    }
            }
        }})
```

**EDIT**

I've updated my code and now I'm getting a 400 status code, based on the /rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-NAME/editmeta

```
data = json.dumps({"fields": { "customfield_SOMEFIELD": {"value": "SOME DATA"}}})
holder = requests.put(searchAPI, json=(data) , auth=(username, password))
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your _code_... the issue may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe I should work backwards, what could cause a 415 error code?

Comment: "The status 415 means that your 'Content-Type' header is not set correctly on the outgoing request. Please make sure you set it correctly for the type of data that JIRA expects to parse."

Comment: I apologize ahead of time, this is my first time asking a question here. I've updated my code for what Jira uses to parse - but now I'm getting a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

header seems to be missing in the put, try including the header information, I am able to update the field with my python requests put code, which is as follows

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import getpass

user=input("enter your username - ")
password= getpass.getpass("enter your password - ")

read_text = open("jira_numbers.txt",'r').read().split('\n')

for jira_num in read_text:
    url="blah_blah_blah"+jira_num
    header = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    jiraF=open("jira_update.json","r")
    jira_load = jiraF.read()
    r = requests.put(url, data = jira_load, headers = header, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user,password))
    print("the json response \n", r.status_code, r.headers )
    print("the response content is \n", r.content)
```

the jira_update.json file content is :

```
{
    "fields": {
                "customfield_13444":"blah_blah"
              }
}
```